# Pass JS Variable from Web Viewer to FM in Web Direct (with no FM Installed)

Tags: javascript, filemaker

I am building an app that will be used by the client via web direct on computers that do not have FileMaker installed.

I need to be able to pass a JS variable from a page displayed in the web viewer to call up a FileMaker record.

I tried writing some js to modify the web viewer URL hash to include the variable and then using getGetLayoutObjectAttribute to parse out the variable, but this function does not work in properly in web direct ( https://community.filemaker.com/thread/77006 )

I was about to attempt to use the fmp protocol scheme to execute a script with the JS variable as a parameter, but I just realized that this solution would require the client's computer to know what to do with fmp:// (ie have FileMaker installed).

Is there any way to pass a js variable to FM when using web direct wihtout FM installed? I can't believe there is no way to do this, but haven't been able to find any information so far.

Thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned on your other question, the fmp url is adressed to the computer hosting the database, i.e. FileMaker Server somewhere. I am not aware of any method to interact from a Web Viewer directly to the client running Web Direct. It has to go through the host with the fmp url scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little CWP (Custom Web Publishing) where you can pass the js variable to a php page, for example. From there you can update a record in FM from the server, and pick it up in your WebDirect session. Works fine.